# Unable to open up localhost in Chrome using MAMP, getting "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, localhost, wamp, mamp

When load up my localhost in Chrome I get the following error in the window:

localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

It doesn't work any any other browsers other than Safari, anyone run into this problem before?

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just incase this helps anyone else it turns out this was a proxy issue and just had to allow localhost:8888 to 'Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains' just enter localhost:8888 into the text box!

Comment: I think this is OSX specific > "System Preferences" > "Network" > "Advanced" then follow the above.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem when I developed a web project with struts.

If you are using proxy(Global Mode) to search API on the Internet in Chrome. You should turn "Global Mode" to "Auto Proxy Mode" to deal with it.